# Position of point in mantissa

Tags: floating-point

I am trying to understand how java works with floating point. As I understand there must be sign,exponent and mantissa in 32 bits (float). However, I can't understand how java defines the decimal part in mantissa. As I understand mantissa can be from `0,....` till `9,......`

The question is how java defines where is position of point. Could anyone explain?

Comment: You need to take a closer look at the [IEEE floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.

Comment: @Marichyasana Sorry. I was thinking float and wrote double. I've corrected.

Comment: There is no decimal point.

Comment: @Boris the Spider Could you explain? I really tried but can't understand.

Comment: The process is a bit involved, but basically the binary number is put in scientific notation and the part after the radix point is used for the mantissa bits and the exponent (how many bits needed to be shifted to get it into the `1.xxxx` form) is represented in the exponent bits (this part is more complicated, but you get the idea) and of course the sign is stored in the sign bit. So, basically, the exponent bits tell us where the radix point is, but the process is more complicated than you seem to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't define how `float` works, IEEE does.

`float` is a binary format so the possible range of the 24-bit mantissa for normal numbers is

```
0b1.0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

to

```
0b1.1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

This represents `1.0` to `2.0 - 1/2^24`

For normal numbers the mantissa always starts with a `1` so it is not actually stored.  This is because the values is

```
sign * 2^exp * mantissa.
```

The exp is adjusted so the mantissa starts `1.`  There are also sub-normal numbers which don't do this, but this only applies to very small numbers.

If you want to see how a float is represented you can have a look at

```
int i = Float.floatToRawIntBits(1.5);
```

The `i` will have the 32-bit value which represents the `float`

Comment: [More info here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/256185/how-is-a-floating-point-number-represented-in-java)

Comment: Technically, Java does define how `float` works in Java. See the JLS, [4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3). According to that section, the floating point types are "conceptually associated with" the IEEE standard types.